# How to move window using custom titlebar in MAUI Blazor

Tags: drag, maui, titlebar

I have a problem with move application.
Window movement works fin, but releasing the button does not work, it moves the window all the time after releasing the left mouse button.

Titlebar razor

```
<div @onpointerdown="() => topbarVM.MouseDown()" @onpointerup="() => topbarVM.MouseUp()" class="flex-row fixed-top p-0 m-0">
```

Code

```
        public void MouseDown()
        {
            isDown = true;
            DragWindow();
        }

        public void MouseUp()
        {
            isDown = false;
        }

        public void DragWindow()
        {
#if WINDOWS
                var mauiWindow = App.Current.Windows.First();
                var nativeWindow = mauiWindow.Handler.PlatformView;
                IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
                WindowId WindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
                AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(WindowId);

                while(isDown)
                {
                    var cursor = GetCursorPosition();
                    appWindow.Move(new Windows.Graphics.PointInt32(cursor.X - 40, cursor.Y - 20));
                }; 
#endif
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is caused by the busyness of the MainThread. You can add the async and await operator for the method you use.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint inside `MouseUp`. Is it ever reached? If not, then your code is keeping MainThread (UI thread) busy, so MouseUp event cannot get processed.

One way to code this (in any UI framework) is to do ONE call on the `MouseMove` event -- not a loop:

```cs
public void MouseMove() {
  if (isDown)
  {
    var mauiWindow ...
    ...
    var cursor = GetCursorPosition();
    appWindow.Move(...
  }
}
```

- Reference `MouseMove()` from an appropriate event in your Blazor code. I don't know Blazor, so I don't show that.

Explanation: after the Move is done, MouseMove returns. This allows internal OS code to process the next event.

Comment: Breakpoint inside MouseUp don't reach, so MainThread must be busy.
I modify my method like you wrote and this work but this solution is too slow.

When I move window and I move pointer too fast then pointer is over window and the method is stopped.